# The binding type 'serviceBusTrigger' is not registered error in azure functions c# with core tools 2

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-webjobs, azureservicebus

I open a fresh new azure functions project, my packages are:

- Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs 3.0.0-beta4
- Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus 3.0.0-beta4
- Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions 1.0.7
- NETStandardLibrary 2.0.1

I use servicebustrigger and my function code is basic:

```
public static class Function1
{
    [FunctionName("OrderPusherFunction")]
    public static Task Run([ServiceBusTrigger("orders","orderpusher", Connection ="ServiceBus")]
    string myQueueItem, TraceWriter log)
    {
        log.Info($"C# Queue trigger function processed: {myQueueItem}");
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

I also have: 
Azure Functions Core Tools (2.0.1-beta.22) and Function Runtime Version: 2.0.11415.0

When i run, i get "**The binding type 'serviceBusTrigger' is not registered**" error, and the function does not get triggered. Anyone has an idea? This looks to me as a basic setup..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basically, in v2 ServiceBus trigger was moved out of the default installation into Extensibility model. You need to register Service Bus binding as an extension as per [Binding Extensions Management](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/wiki/Binding-Extensions-Management).

Unfortunately, this is all work-in-progress, as there is a number of issues for Service Bus binding:

- [Migrate ServiceBus Extension to .NET Core](https://github.com/azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/1329) - "Done", but see the comments for which problems still exist
- [Build failure after installing ExtensionsMetadatGenerator into empty v2 app](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/624) prevents VS tooling from registering the extension properly
- [Extensions.json is not updated when "extension install" CLI command executed for service bus extension](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/issues/2238) for CLI issue

My advice would be to stick to v1 for now.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and that's exactly what i did in the meantime, went back to net461, downgraded packages and it started working. We'll give it more time to mature up then..

Comment: @EmreErtugrul have you migrated azure functions version to 1.x or it is still 2.0 ?