# "The binding type(s) 'queueTrigger' are not registered" error randomly appearing.

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have a function 2.0 that has a queue trigger and works as expected.

Yet, from some days on, sometimes I realize the messages are not being processed. I go to the function details in the portal and see the following error:

```
The binding type(s) 'queueTrigger' are not registered. Please ensure the type is correct and the binding extension is installed.
```

This is accompanied by a error 500 when I directly try to access https://function_app_name.azurewebsites.net/

After I stop and restart the app it usually starts working again. Anyone with the same behaviour happening?

I'm deploying from VS Community Mac

Comment: Did you see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48295848/the-binding-type-servicebustrigger-is-not-registered-error-in-azure-functions) thread ?

Comment: @Jayendran Yes. But I have everything set up correctly and most of the times it is working. Just sometimes, randomly, it stops and that error comes up. I assume is some bug in Azure (otherwise it would never work)

Comment: We are running into this error with .Net Core 2.2. runtime.   I have also upgraded to the latest Nuget Packages.  "Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="3.0.3 and ""Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions" Version="3.0.6"

Answer (score 2):

You can try to delete the local temporary folder related to "Functions"
C:\Users....\AppData\Local\Temp\Functions\ExtensionBundles

For the reference : https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/4909#issuecomment-530148249

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this issue by updating the versions of the following NuGet packages:

```
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage v3.0.4
Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions v1.0.2
```

To the latest versions.

```
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage v3.0.10
Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions v1.0.29
```

Comment: This is a common problem when switching from v2.x -> v3.x. This update is recommended to every "old" Azure Function project after installing .NET Core 3.x and deploying to Azure.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing same issue. I eventually sorted it out by manually registering *Extension bundles* in *host.config* according to [following doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local?tabs=windows#register-extensions).

```
{
    "version": "2.0",
    "extensionBundle": {
        "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
        "version": "[1.*, 2.0.0)"
    }
}
```

Also, here is summary of my referenced NuGet packages just in case:

```
<PackageReference Include="Autofac" Version="4.6.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" Version="5.2.7" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs" Version="3.0.14" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions" Version="3.0.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage" Version="3.0.10" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Data.OData" Version="5.8.4" />
<PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="12.0.2" />
<PackageReference Include="System.Net.Http.WinHttpHandler" Version="4.5.3" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="1.0.24" />
<PackageReference Include="System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager" Version="4.5.0" />
```

Answer (score 0):

There are breaking changes in 2.0.12050-alpha, you have two options to choose in the [doc](https://github.com/Azure/app-service-announcements/issues/129) for you Function.

One is upgrade your extensions and configure the settings. You could get this just follow the steps in the doc.

The other one is pin your Function App to the previous version of the runtime by updating the app setting `FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION` to 2.0.11961-alpha. You could get details information under the title **What can I do to avoid being impacted?**.

If you still have related problems, you could let me know or go to [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/3363) and check if someone has encountered this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error "`The binding type(s) 'queueTrigger' are not registered. Please ensure the type is correct and the binding extension is installed.`" with output log

```
Exception thrown: 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
'func.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded …
```

Not exactly sure what was wrong but following some hints from [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/3919) I updated all nuget packages for which an updated version was available and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Agreeing with Adrian Toman.

The changes I made were:

```
-    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage" Version="3.0.0" />
+    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage" Version="3.0.10" />
-    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="1.0.24" />
+    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="1.0.29" />
```

And this seemed to resolve the issue. Strange though.

My timeline:

```
2019-09-23: Deployed with old versions of packages, queues work fine
2019-10-24: New deploy with old versions, all queue triggers fail
2019-10-25: Updated packages above, things are working again.
```

So it would appear some sort of breaking change was made on the azure side after 2019-09-23.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same error on Azure when updating a v1 Azure function to v3.  I had updated AzureFunctionsVersion in the csproj to v3 but left the TargetFramework as net472.  I needed to update AzureFunctionsVersion to v3 and also TargetFramework to netcoreapp3.1 (see screenshot below).

I also updated host.json with:

```
"version": "2.0"
```

[image: csproj config]

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked after I deleted the extensions bundle again and forced the download again . And it solved . Somehow I sense inconsistency in the way the extensions bundling is being handled .